# Detect UNITY UI image only moves inside another image or rect transform

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have two image in my unity scene.
One of this images is an square as background `Recttransform` and another image is a button.

I use **Drag Event** for this button to detect movement in run time.

But I want to move this button only inside the background image.

And I don't know how to make this limitation.
Is there any solution for this issue ?

For more explanation please see this image :
[image: my problem]

Comment: You want to limit the image's movement bounds? (it can't leave the background's border), or you want to move it in relation to the background's position (if the background image moves, the foreground image should move with it as if it were glued in place)?

Comment: hi. my explanation is very clear !!!  i said i want to move the blue button inside the red background square only. not in out side of that. @ErikOverflow

Comment: `Mathf.Clamp` on the coordinates and the parent's rect's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, here are a two ways to do this:

1. Create a few invisible box colliders and place them at the edge of the red square. Probably easiest but more prone to issues when screen size changes.
2. Get [Screen.width, Screen.height](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-width.html), [Rect.width, and Rect.height](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect-width.html). Only allow drag up to the edges of the screen minus 1/2 Rect.width and 1/2 Rect.height.